# В чем смысл предложения?

Tags: смысл

В предложении

> "Неисполнение должностным лицом государственного органа республики, органа местного самоуправления, организации, независимо от организационно-правовой формы, законных требований депутата законодательного органа либо создание препятствий в осуществлении его деятельности - влечет наложение административного штрафа в размере от трех тысяч до пяти тысяч рублей."

вторая часть после союза либо "создание препятствий в осуществлении его деятельности" относится к словам из первой части "должностным лицом государственного органа республики, органа местного самоуправления, организации" или после "либо" отдельно надо понимать?

Answer (score 1):

Если упростить:

> Неисполнение такими-то лицами требований депутата либо создание
>   препятствий в его деятельности наказывается штрафом.

Неясности создаёт употребление местоимения "его (деятельности)": по смыслу правдоподобнее препятствование деятельности депутата, но позже упоминания о нём упомянут и "законодательный орган", "осуществлению деятельности" которого тоже можно препятствовать.

Answer (score 0):

Это обычный канцелярит, и в нём всё на месте.

> Неисполнение должностным лицом государственного органа республики,
>   органа местного самоуправления, организации, независимо от
>   организационно-правовой формы, законных требований депутата
>   законодательного органа либо создание препятствий в осуществлении его
>   деятельности - влечет наложение административного штрафа в размере от
>   трех тысяч до пяти тысяч рублей.

Убираем определения - получаем в сухом остатке:

*Неисполнение либо создание препятствий должностным лицом требований депутата влечет наложение штрафа,* -

конструкция неграмотна, зато видно, кто на ком стоял;

хотите "красиво"(=грамотно) - получите канцелярит.

Можно так попробовать:

*Неисполнение требований депутата либо создание препятствий в осуществлении его деятельности должностным лицом влечет наложение штрафа.*